# Joomla blank after moving to server

Tags: joomla

I just migrated a Joomla website from one server to another, copied all the files, imported the db and changed the db parameters in the configuration.php file. But now the Joomla site just shows a blank page (not just admin page, front page too!). All the files are present and the import to the db was succesful.

This is the address: http://astrorama.nl/joomla

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a PHP or webserver error when executing your code. You may want to see if your web host offers an error log to view. Usually these "white screens of death" are due to either permissions or ownership problems on the files that have been uploaded, but for verification purposes, check the (usually [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)) error logs.